# Multiple API requests in a single Widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I'm trying to switch to flutter now because of the freedom of creativity flutter gives to developers.

I now know how to achieve my desired UI designs but one important thing is the UX.

I've setup my app like this.

```
class HomeFragment extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeFragment({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        color: Color(colorBackground),
        child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        height: 180,
                        child: MyUsersWidget(),
                      ),
                      Container(
                          child: Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          UserImages(),
                        ],
                      )),
                    ],
                  )))
        ]));
  }
}
```

**MyUsersWidget** is a Horizontal `ListView` that shows `Images` of Users and has an `API request` to `GET` all user images inside it.

**UserImages** is a Vertical `ListView` that shows `Images` with image names and has an `API request` to `GET` all images and their names inside it too.

THEY HAVE DIFFERENT API ENDPOINTS.

What I'm experiencing right now is, when I debug, **MyUsersWidget's** API request gets called first then it freezes the result to a certain point.

Then when I hit "CTRL+S" it then continues to **UserImages's** API request and then shows all the data.

what's the most optimized way to call for Multiple API request?

and why is it that it freezes and then continues when I hot reload?

Thank you very much for the knowledge you're about to share!

Comment: Can you show the code in MyUsersWidget ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide how API requests are called. One possible cause of the request getting stalled is the likely use of [await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#working-with-futures-async-and-await) keyword. Using `await` will let the Widget *wait* for the completed result of the asynchronous function before proceeding.

As for why the app displays the data on screen upon [hot reload](https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/hot-reload#how-to-perform-a-hot-reload). A likely cause of this scenario is that the API request has successfully completed and hitting hot reload displayed the data on the Widget before proceeding to the next API request.